# Sharepoint 2010 service application .Net Version

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, .net-4.5, service-application

I'm designing a service application for SharePoint 2010 and I want to know if my services have to use .net 3.5 or not. I've checked MSDN but I could not found a clear article or even a phrase about this.

I would hate to develop everything and then discover that I could not have use .net 4.5.
I would greatly appreciate direct answers such as "Yes you can use any version of the framework you want" or maybe "Yes, check this out LINK HERE, if he used so can you".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharepoint 2010 is based on .net 3.5SP1, so no 4.0 or 4.5 features can be used.

Sharepoint 2013 is based on .net 4.5, not that it matters in this case.